# MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Attacker' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am getting the above error and I tried to use debug.log to print where the error is.
I am creating a type of tank obj. which fire to some instantiated obj. Instantiated object are attacker.

In update I am using foreach loop to loop through all the instantiated object. If found and If object are in range fire.

```
void Update () {
        
        if (attacker!= null  )
        {
            //Debug.Log("inside att");
            attacker = FindObjectsOfType<Attacker>();
        }
        
        // fire only if attacker is in range 
        
        if (IfInRange() && attacker!= null && running)
        {
          
            faceTowardTarget();
            Fire();
        }
       
    }
    bool IfInRange()
    {// run through all the instantiated attacker
        foreach (Attacker currentAttacker in attacker)
```

**This works fine but sometimes gives above. At the end in the console the loop goes on and on and currentAttacker is null in the end. I tried to print that in console. but it don't go in other if statement**

```
{   //if attacker is in range
            
            if (attacker != null )
                {
                    
                    Debug.Log(currentAttacker.GetComponent<Health>().isAlive);
                   
                    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, currentAttacker.transform.position) < minDistance)               
                    {
                        
                        attackerPos = currentAttacker.transform;
                        
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (currentAttacker == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("curre Attacker null");
                    running = false;
                    return false;
                }
                
             }return false;
        }
```

Attacker have a simple health script which deal with damage if hit by projectile.

```
Void update()
    {
     if (health <= 0)
            {
**is there any better way to destroy an obj. If i destroy gameObject that error appear and it get stuck in foreach loop**
               // Destroy(gameObject);
                noOfKilled++;
                isAlive = false;
                scoreHolder.addScore(scoreValue);
            }
    }
```

Thank you so much for helping. I tried searching but unable to resolve this.

Comment: Can u post the whole stack trace ?

Comment: Well, you've got a lot of jacked up logic.  In your `Update()`, `if` check, swap `IsInRange()` and `attacker != null`.  If not, you're going into `IsInRange()` with a `null` attacker (Maybe).  Now, you can remove your attacker null checks in `IsInRange()` which could've made your `foreach` loop pop.  Also, `currentAttacker` is not going to be null, it just won't be in your list.  You need to maintain a flag

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding out the error. Thank you, game development is the only thing I want to do in this life. Without the help of you guys I can't do that. Because it is really a bit difficult to do everything by yourself. Thank you .

Comment: @jiveturkey Thank you jiveturkey for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Comment: Thanks much for the kudos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to fix this is to use the `DestroyImmediate` function instead of the `Destroy` function. Using `DestroyImmediate(gameObject)` will destroy the object in that frame and `FindObjectsOfType<Attacker>()` cannot find it so it won't be accessed in the `foreach` loop.

---

The proper way to this is to create a `List` in your main code to hold the instantiated `Attacker` script:

```
public GameObject attackerPrefab;
public List<Attacker> attacker = new List<Attacker>();
```

When you instantiate the prefab, *add* the `Attacker` script to the `List`:

```
//Instantiate
GameObject obj = Instantiate(attackerPrefab);
//Get Attacker component 
Attacker tempAttacker = obj.GetComponent<Attacker>();
//Add Attacker component to List
attacker.Add(tempAttacker);
```

Finally, when you want to destroy the attacker object in your health script, *remove* it from the `List` then destroy it. By removing it from the `List` before destroying it, you won't be accessing an object marked as destroyed.

```
//Get the script that stores the List of Attacker
Test otherScript = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectYourScriptIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Test>();
//Remove from the List
otherScript.attacker.Remove(gameObject.GetComponent<Attacker>());
//Now, destroy this gameObject
Destroy(gameObject);
```

Comment: Thank you so much you have solved a lot of my problem. Thank you. I m really thankful to you guys for helping guys like me. Who knows very little programming and dreaming of becoming a game developer one day. Earlier I don't use list's in my programming but now I am really loving it . i have changed my code a but and use the list and take obj from that list. Nice clean. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I able able to help

Comment: Thank you for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Comment: No problem at all. You need to rig the snow man otherwise, it's boring staring at a  static character with only transform movement. After rigging it, create an idle and moving animation for it. It will make it look better. See [this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/2d-arm-rig) tutorial to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try something to do with now...:) Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

There many options to solve this problem. One Option is don't use a foreach loop when u edit the loop. But when u want to keep the foreach loop just save the objects in a other list and destroy them after the foreach loop.

Example1

```
for(int i = 0; i < attackers.Count; i++)
            {
                //if in range
                attackers.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;
            }
```

Example2

```
List<string> attackers = new List<string>();
        List<string> _shootAt = new List<string>();
        foreach(string attacker in attackers)
        {
            //if in range
            _shootAt.Add(attacker);
        }

        foreach (string attacker in _shootAt)
        {
            //if in range
            attackers.Remove(attacker);
        }
```

I hope that can help you

Comment: Thank you so much for helping Z3RP. without the help of you guys I can't solve these error which is created my me only. Thank you .Thank you. You all are hero.

Comment: Thank you Z3RP for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume, the error shows up when instantiating another tank after the first tank is destroyed? all your tanks are clones of tank1, so when tank1 is destroyed, you get a null pointer, because its trying to instantiate an object thats not there anymore.

2 solutions...

A) UGLY: change tank1's initial position to somewhere it will never be destroyed, say 5000,5000,5000. since the tank cant be destroyed, it will never be null

B) THE SMART, CORRECT WAY: make a prefab. make a folder called prefabs, drag tank1 into it. select your script which spawns tanks, and drag the PREFAB copy of tank1 into it. now you always have an instance of tank1 and your null pointer is gone!

i cannot stress enough the importance of proper use of prefabs, not just for performance and reliabilty, but sanity as well...

Comment: Thank you so much Vanethrane. I will go with B. I am trying to be Smart. but rite now I write code which is UGLY but learning with the help of you guys will make me and my code SMART. One day. Hope So.:)

Comment: Thank you Vanethrane for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Comment: thanks for the mention buddy! good game! i tried it out and enjoyed it. glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
FindObjectsOfType<Attacker>(); //returns an array
```

will return an array, not an object, use attackers[0] for firstone or use

`FindObjectOfType<Attacker>()`

(will return the first found).

Using objectsOfType you always have an empty array, so

`if (attacker==null)`

of course will return false because the array isn't null, its just empty. This is why it doesn't go in your second if statement;

Also

```
void update()
        {
         if (health <= 0)
                {
    **is there any better way to destroy an obj. If i destroy gameObject that error appear and it get stuck in foreach loop**

                    noOfKilled++;
                    isAlive = false;
                    scoreHolder.addScore(scoreValue);
                    Destroy(gameObject);// destroy it after at the end, not before it have something else to do
                }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you victor. I have use List and now I think it is really a nice thing to use that. :)

Comment: Thank you victor dabija for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game.I have mention you name in description hope you don't mind.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman